# Ubuntu randomly reboots on new computer without logging any relevant events; how can I find out what's going on?

Tags: reboot, logging

I'm having an issue with a new computer; it randomly reboots.  Not a crash...just,  Like someone pulled the plug.

No logs are recording any events,  they just...stop.    Is there a way to force Ubuntu to record what's happening here?  Or does anyone know if Intel motherboards have some sort of logging system?

Comment: I suggest you update the question with more specific details, like which version of Ubuntu are you using.

Comment: The answer is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564735/linux-kernel-org-misleading-about-kernel-panic-proc-sys-kernel-panic  ; however, I've seen enough questions about this to suspect it doesn't always work and there may also be reasons other than a kernel panic that would cause a reboot -- for example, a failing power supply or a loose power cord.

Comment: Also, if you have a high power video card and a power supply not rated to handle it, the system will very likely reboot when the video card use goes up and overloads the power supply.  There are options in nvidia-smi (assuming an nvidia video card) to limit power use -- this is the best way to confirm this issue.

Comment: There is no secret motherboard logging system that persists after a poweroff or reboot. Persistent logging is an OS function.

Comment: @user535733: that's true on consumer grade hardware.  Server grade hardware does have logging.   Also, it could help to enable network logging or serial logging, but that assumes you've got hardware on the other end of that to receive it.

Comment: It looks like  a RAM issue to me, I'd suggest using a memtest86 off a live ISO.

Answer (score 2):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Good idea...assuming the system got a chance to log anything before rebooting.

Comment: Thank you. Ill give this a try.

Comment: in the middle of typing a comment to thank you,  it crashed out again.   Here's what the command shows me https://hastebin.com/emezanamaj.apache

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in that log.  The actual reason probably didn't get saved before the crash.